# Select certain elements of response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I found myself not understanding how I can select only some elements of my Steam API request response.

Here is the code with the results that makes a correct request on Steam. It is non-reproducable because client_id is personal information. The results are included.

```
# All online streamers
client_id = "...confidential"
limit = "2"
def request_dataNewAPI(limit):
    headers = {"Client-ID": client_id, "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json"}
    url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?first=" + limit
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    return r
    # If a bad user login name or offline response will be:
    # {'data': [], 'pagination': {}}

table1 = request_dataNewAPI(limit)
```

The output is:

```
New API 

{'data': [{'id': '34472839600', 'user_id': '12826', 'user_name': 'Twitch', 'game_id': '509663', 'community_ids': ['f261cf73-cbcc-4b08-af72-c6d2020f9ed4'], 'type': 'live', 'title': 'The 1st Ever 3rd or 4th Pre Pre Show! Part 6', 'viewer_count': 19555, 'started_at': '2019-06-10T02:01:20Z', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail_url': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_twitch-{width}x{height}.jpg', 'tag_ids': ['d27da25e-1ee2-4207-bb11-dd8d54fa29ec', '6ea6bca4-4712-4ab9-a906-e3336a9d8039']}, {'id': '34474693232', 'user_id': '39298218', 'user_name': 'dakotaz', 'game_id': '33214', 'community_ids': [], 'type': 'live', 'title': '  | code: dakotaz in itemshop & GFUEL', 'viewer_count': 15300, 'started_at': '2019-06-10T06:37:02Z', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail_url': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_dakotaz-{width}x{height}.jpg', 'tag_ids': ['6ea6bca4-4712-4ab9-a906-e3336a9d8039']}], 'pagination': {'cursor': 'eyJiIjpudWxsLCJhIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6Mn19'}}
```

The problem is that I want to select only the list of 'user_name' of active streamers. I tried the following:

```
print(table1['data']['user_name'])
```

gives "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

```
print(table1['data'])
```

gives the whole array of data:

```
[{'id': '34472839600', 'user_id': '12826', 'user_name': 'Twitch', 'game_id': '509663', 'community_ids': ['f261cf73-cbcc-4b08-af72-c6d2020f9ed4'], 'type': 'live', 'title': 'The 1st Ever 3rd or 4th Pre Pre Show! Part 6', 'viewer_count': 19555, 'started_at': '2019-06-10T02:01:20Z', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail_url': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_twitch-{width}x{height}.jpg', 'tag_ids': ['d27da25e-1ee2-4207-bb11-dd8d54fa29ec', '6ea6bca4-4712-4ab9-a906-e3336a9d8039']}, {'id': '34474693232', 'user_id': '39298218', 'user_name': 'dakotaz', 'game_id': '33214', 'community_ids': [], 'type': 'live', 'title': '  | code: dakotaz in itemshop & GFUEL', 'viewer_count': 15300, 'started_at': '2019-06-10T06:37:02Z', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail_url': 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_dakotaz-{width}x{height}.jpg', 'tag_ids': ['6ea6bca4-4712-4ab9-a906-e3336a9d8039']}]
```

As a final result, I would like to have something like:

```
'user_name': {name1, name2}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I want to select only the list of 'user_name' of active streamers
>   ... `print(table1['data']['user_name'])`
>   ... gives `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`.

You receive `TypeError` because `table1['data']` is a `list`, not `dict` and you must access its members with `int`, not `str` (although `dict` keys can be `int` as well).

Use [list comprehension](https://hackernoon.com/list-comprehension-in-python-c762ba1f523f):

```py
user_names = [x['user_name'] for x in table1['data']]
```

This will give you the `list` of strings representing user names.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan! Works just fine.